# Unable to call primary constructor for Recipe class org.openrewrite.github.AddCronTrigger in org.openrewrite.java.migrate.Java8toJava11

Tags: java, openrewrite

I'm having some trouble trying the <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.migrate.Java8toJava11</recipe>

When we execute the maven goal it fails with this error:

org.openrewrite.config.RecipeIntrospectionException[m: [1;31mUnable to call primary constructor for Recipe class org.openrewrite.github.AddCronTrigger

```
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Unable to configure org.openrewrite.github.AddCronTrigger
[1;31morg.openrewrite.config.RecipeIntrospectionException[m: [1;31mUnable to call primary constructor for Recipe class org.openrewrite.github.AddCronTrigger[m
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.internal.RecipeIntrospectionUtils.getRecipeIntrospectionException ([1mRecipeIntrospectionUtils.java:140[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.internal.RecipeIntrospectionUtils.construct ([1mRecipeIntrospectionUtils.java:134[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.internal.RecipeIntrospectionUtils.constructRecipe ([1mRecipeIntrospectionUtils.java:102[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.configureRecipes ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:165[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.scanClasses ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:135[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.<init> ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:60[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.Environment$Builder.scanRuntimeClasspath ([1mEnvironment.java:224[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.environment ([1mAbstractRewriteMojo.java:123[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults ([1mAbstractRewriteMojo.java:213[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute ([1mAbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:53[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo ([1mDefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 ([1mMojoExecutor.java:370[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:351[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:215[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:171[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:163[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject ([1mLifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject ([1mLifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build ([1mSingleThreadedBuilder.java:56[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute ([1mLifecycleStarter.java:128[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:294[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:192[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:105[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute ([1mMavenCli.java:960[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain ([1mMavenCli.java:293[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main ([1mMavenCli.java:196[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 ([1mNative Method[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ([1mNativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ([1mDelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43[m)
    [1mat[m java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke ([1mMethod.java:566[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced ([1mLauncher.java:282[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch ([1mLauncher.java:225[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode ([1mLauncher.java:406[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main ([1mLauncher.java:347[m)
[1mCaused by[m: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 ([1mNative Method[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance ([1mNativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance ([1mDelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45[m)
    [1mat[m java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance ([1mConstructor.java:490[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.internal.RecipeIntrospectionUtils.construct ([1mRecipeIntrospectionUtils.java:131[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.internal.RecipeIntrospectionUtils.constructRecipe ([1mRecipeIntrospectionUtils.java:102[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.configureRecipes ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:165[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.scanClasses ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:135[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.<init> ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:60[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.Environment$Builder.scanRuntimeClasspath ([1mEnvironment.java:224[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.environment ([1mAbstractRewriteMojo.java:123[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults ([1mAbstractRewriteMojo.java:213[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute ([1mAbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:53[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo ([1mDefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 ([1mMojoExecutor.java:370[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:351[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:215[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:171[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:163[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject ([1mLifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject ([1mLifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build ([1mSingleThreadedBuilder.java:56[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute ([1mLifecycleStarter.java:128[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:294[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:192[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:105[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute ([1mMavenCli.java:960[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain ([1mMavenCli.java:293[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main ([1mMavenCli.java:196[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 ([1mNative Method[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ([1mNativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ([1mDelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43[m)
    [1mat[m java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke ([1mMethod.java:566[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced ([1mLauncher.java:282[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch ([1mLauncher.java:225[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode ([1mLauncher.java:406[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main ([1mLauncher.java:347[m)
[1mCaused by[m: java.lang.NullPointerException
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.github.AddCronTrigger.parseExpression ([1mAddCronTrigger.java:71[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.github.AddCronTrigger.<init> ([1mAddCronTrigger.java:54[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.github.AddCronTrigger.<init> ([1mAddCronTrigger.java:64[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 ([1mNative Method[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance ([1mNativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance ([1mDelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45[m)
    [1mat[m java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance ([1mConstructor.java:490[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.internal.RecipeIntrospectionUtils.construct ([1mRecipeIntrospectionUtils.java:131[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.internal.RecipeIntrospectionUtils.constructRecipe ([1mRecipeIntrospectionUtils.java:102[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.configureRecipes ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:165[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.scanClasses ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:135[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.<init> ([1mClasspathScanningLoader.java:60[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.config.Environment$Builder.scanRuntimeClasspath ([1mEnvironment.java:224[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.environment ([1mAbstractRewriteMojo.java:123[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults ([1mAbstractRewriteMojo.java:213[m)
    [1mat[m org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute ([1mAbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:53[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo ([1mDefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 ([1mMojoExecutor.java:370[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:351[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:215[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:171[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute ([1mMojoExecutor.java:163[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject ([1mLifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject ([1mLifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build ([1mSingleThreadedBuilder.java:56[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute ([1mLifecycleStarter.java:128[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:294[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:192[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute ([1mDefaultMaven.java:105[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute ([1mMavenCli.java:960[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain ([1mMavenCli.java:293[m)
    [1mat[m org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main ([1mMavenCli.java:196[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 ([1mNative Method[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ([1mNativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62[m)
    [1mat[m jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ([1mDelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43[m)
    [1mat[m java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke ([1mMethod.java:566[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced ([1mLauncher.java:282[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch ([1mLauncher.java:225[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode ([1mLauncher.java:406[m)
    [1mat[m org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main ([1mLauncher.java:347[m)
```

This is my pom.xml configuration:

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>5.3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <activeRecipes>
              <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.migrate.UseJavaUtilBase64</recipe>
            </activeRecipes>
          </configuration>
           <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-migrate-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's been a fix to `rewrite-github-actions`, which is a transitive dependency of `rewrite-migrate-java`. Until the next full release you might want to add a dependency on this version to get the fix already: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-github-actions/releases/tag/v2.0.3

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Tim, I'm having the same error related to AddCronTrigger when trying to execute the Migrate to Spring 3 plugin:
mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:run \
  -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-spring:LATEST \
  -Drewrite.activeRecipes=org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_1
I'm having a hard time figuring out how / where to include the dependency to rewrite-github-actions 2.0.3. Is there a way to specify it directly in the command line or should I include it as another plugin dependency for rewrite-maven-plugin?

Comment: There's also been a new release of rewrite spring. You'll want to use 5.0.6±